# container passing this.props to another function does pass a copy

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux with structuredSelectors, redux-actions and connect (react-redux) as a HOC in a component. Where I have bound some dispatcher and some selectors to my container.

I now want to outsource some of my container logic into some other files/ functions, these functions should make use of the dispatcher and selected properties of my container (this.props of my container).

lets say I have a function called demo:

```
function demo(props){
  // here is my logic where I work with some dispatchers 
  // and selected store properties of my container
}
```

now inside my container im calling the demo function like this

```
function CONTAINER_FUNC_XXX(){
    demo(this.props) 
}
```

somehow my demo function receives a copy of the properties.
I came to this conclusion since while running the demo functions logic, some dispatchers gets called which should change some of the selector properties of props, which doesnt happen.

Therefore I wanna know, how I can pass the pointer to props, instead of a copy. And why the hell does javascript copy the props since it is a deeply nested object, It should actually just pass a pointer...

**-------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------**

Here is a better example of the problem.

when my mouseController.mouseDown gets called, first I fire the demoDispatcher, which calls a reducer, this reducer manipulates the demoStoreProp (actually this property is an array which gets reseted to an empty array). When I log the demoStoreProp inside the mouseController it returns me the wrong property. Since my dispatcher actions are all synchronously I'm concluding, that the props argument in my controller function is a copy.

## CONATINER

```
// MY CONTAINER APP

import * as mouseController from './mouseController'

class App extends React.Component {

   componentDidMount(){
     ...
     // here I am registering the classes/containers handleMouseDown function 
     // on the global/windows onmousedown event
     window.onmousedown = (e) => this.handleMouseDown(e);
     ...
   }

   handleMouseDown(e){
      // CONTROLLER CALL
      mouseController.mouseDown(e, this.props);

      // LOGS CORRECT VAR (empty array)
      console.log(this.props.demoStoreProp)
  };

  ...

}


// here are my store selected properties
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  ...
  demoStoreProp : [SELECTOR FUNC INSERTING THE PROP INTO THE CONTAINERS PROPS]
  ...
})

// here are my dispatcher properties
const mapStateToDispatch = {
  ...
  demoDispatch : [AN ACTION FROM AN ACTION CREATOR]
  ...
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapStateToDispatch
)(App)
```

## CONTROLLER

```
export function mouseDown(e, props){

  // calling the dispatcher with props
  props.demoDispatch();

  // LOGS WRONG VAR (filled array)
  console.log(props.demoStoreProp)

}
```

Comment: please, show the code of your container

Comment: Tomorrow ( or soon )  I will try to prepare a Demo of this problem. But the Problem is actually really described good enough to maybe explain me, how the Container properties can get passed correctly

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: is `handleMouseDown` binded with `this` in `constructor`?

Comment: no it is not, but since the function fires just normally, I thought this i not a problem